# Difference Between 2 Ways to Start Async Task Without Waiting in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

An asynchronous method like below should be executed without waiting in a ASP.NET MVC website.

```
public async Task DoStaff()
{
    // business logic here
}
```

And we found two solutions to accomplish this and both work on our testbed:

**Solution 1**:

```
public void DoStaffWrapper()
{
    DoStaff();
    // clean up
}

public ActionResult Caller()
{
    DoStaffWrapper();
    // return blah blah blah;
}
```

**Solution 2**:

```
public async Task DoStaffWrapperAsync()
{
    await DoStaff();
    // clean up
}

public ActionResult Caller()
{
    Task.Run(() => DoStaffWrapperAsync());
    // return blah blah blah;    
}
```

So what is the difference between them? which is the better and why? Any benefits?

Comment: Okay. Let me rename it into "Right".

Comment: If you want reliable execution, [the "right" way is to place the work into a reliable queue (e.g., Azure Queue) and have an independent background process (e.g., Azure Function) reading from the queue and processing the work](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks! I read your article before asking. Eventually I didn't run the methods in background. And I raised a question here because I saw many "Solution 2" in the codebase and wanted to know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have precise control over the lifecycle of your IIS pool (or unless you're not actually running on IIS), you should use [`QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636892(v=vs.110).aspx) to launch your fire-and-forget tasks. It makes sure the runtime is able to track them, and won't terminate prematurely the process.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ => DoStaff());
```

If for some reason you don't want to use this method, or don't need it, there's an important difference between the two ways of calling the async method:

- `DoStaff()` will run synchronously on the current thread until an `await` statement is found, then it will yield control over the thread (and whatever you have after `DoStaff` will be able to execute. Also, the mehtod will execute inside of ASP.NET's synchronization context, so you will run into trouble if you're not using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` whenever awaiting calls inside of it.
- `Task.Run(() => DoStaffWrapperAsync())` will entirely run asynchronously, and in a separate context (so you won't run into the aforementioned issue).

To put it simple, take the following method:

```
public Task DoStaff()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    await AnotherMethodAsync();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

If you call `DoStaff`, the call will be blocking for one second. If you call `Task.Run(() => DoStaff())`, the call will return immediately. But if there's no significant amount of work before the first `await`, then you'll be jumping to a new thread for no practical gain.

Comment: It's deployed to Azure as Website. I can't control IIS much.

Comment: @Vej Then `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is the way to go